# CodeIgniter 'MySQL has Gone Away'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I know there are many topics about MySQL's "Server has gone away" error, but this one seems to be happening randomly and in a non-favorable condition.

I'm using CodeIgniter 3.0. In the research I did, I found [someone else with this problem](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/245106/#1067534) using this framework but that issue was never solved. He/she stated that it was CodeIgniter's fault because the database had no problems with other applications.

People say this issue is usually because of a timeout, but I don't think there could be a timeout where the amount of data is minimal. In fact, the tables where I'm trying to pick up information from have no more than 5 rows. I'm just doing a `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = x` so I don't really think that there's a performance issue with that amount of data.

My code for the query goes as follows:

```
public function getArticleByRef($ref)
            {
                $this->db->reconnect();
                $article = array();
                $mods = array();
                $run = array();
                $supplier=array();
                $query = ($this->db->get_where('PABE_articles',array('Reference' => $ref),1));
                $article = $query->result_array();

                if(!$article)
                    return array('article' => null,'mods' => $mods,'run' => $run,'supplier'=>$supplier);
                $id = $article[0]['id'];
                $query = $this->db->get_where('PABE_mods',array('idarticle'=>$id));
                $mods = $query->result_array();
                $query = $this->db->select('*')
                    ->from('PABE_run')
                    ->where('idarticle', $id)
                    ->order_by('Color asc,Number asc')
                    ->get();
                $run = $query->result_array();
                $query = $this->db->get_where('PABE_supplieres',array('Reference' => $article[0]['Referencesupplier']));
                $supplier=  $query->result_array();
                return array('article' => $article,'mods' => $mods,'run' => $run,'supplier'=>$supplier);
            }
```

As you can see, I do four queries. Then again, in none of these tables there's more than 5 rows.

The number of columns for the tables are:

```
Articles: 27
Supplier: 2
Run: 3
Mods: 4
```

The problem is totally random, so I can't complete this application without fixing it. Something that's pretty weird is that, even though this problem gets reported, all data from the database gets loaded with no problems.

Everything's running on my PC - Localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be that your mysql is not configured to support persistent connections. Try commenting the reconnect line or edit my.ini and enable persistent connections.

regards

Comment: I added the reconnect() line because of this problem in fact. It was one of the solutions I found on internet that didn't work. Also, persistent connections are enabled in CodeIgniter by default. My application has it enabled: 'pconnect' => TRUE. I will try disabling it, though. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Ok get lucky and post results

Comment: Ok, Been working with the app and, so far, no problem at all. It happened at least once or twice every 1/2 hours, so I will assume that it's fixed. Thanks a lot for pointing me to the right direction :)!

Comment: It's fine to know this ;)

Comment: Just to update: The error did not come back at all. I'd say it's solved :) Thanks a lot!