# Why does it give error after flashdata message?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

In Codeigniter, while I insert a new data, the website was freezing. I cannot click anywhere. I set flash data, and after I insert a new data, the website is locking. After refresh website, It gives this error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: HY000/2006

MySQL server has gone away

SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `cusId` = '1'

Filename: controllers/Vehicles.php

Line Number: 454
```

It gives more errors like that.

My Controller:

```
............

$insert = $this -> db -> insert("vehicles", $data);

            if ($insert) {

                if($this->session->userdata('people_lang') == 'en') {$this->session->set_flashdata("success", "Vehicle has been Added Successfully!"); }
                elseif($this->session->userdata('people_lang') == 'ar') {$this->session->set_flashdata("success", "تمت إضافة السيارة بنجاح!"); }

                redirect(base_url("vehicles"));

            } else {

                if($this->session->userdata('people_lang') == 'en') {$this->session->set_flashdata("error", "An Error Occurred during the Process."); }
                elseif($this->session->userdata('people_lang') == 'ar') {$this->session->set_flashdata("error", "حدث خطأ أثناء العملية."); }

                redirect(base_url("vehicles"));

            }
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM customer..` is not `INSERT into vehicles`, please show relevant code.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you don't need to pass `base_url` to  `redirect` it will figure that out for you. Use `redirect('vehicles') instead.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is due to `set_flashdata`? If you remove those calls does the problem go away?

Comment: without set_flashdata, It gives no error. When I added set flashdata it gives MySQL server has gone away errors.

Comment: where is the problem? Anyone helps?

Comment: Try changing the redirects to controller/method instead of just 'controller' ... CI can act strangely if you don't and flashdata is already a bit tricky.

Comment: Can you show your solution as an answer?

Comment: **Read this**
[Mysql gone away stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746312/codeigniter-mysql-has-gone-away#27746484)

Comment: It is not only about Mysql gone away, I think its about flashdata.

Comment: @Mark did you figure out a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the database driver to your auto loads?

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html

If your application im has heavy database usage this would be a good idea. Otherwise you can manually call the driver and reconnect before you execute your query.